# Hibernate Get and load method

Tags: hibernate, load

> I have basic understanding of both the methods but I have few concerns for Load() method:
>   1. If class is final or default constructor is not provided ,in that case load will always hit the database or throw error as it’s not able to create proxy class?
>   2. If object is found in first or second level cache , it will return full object or proxy object?

For Get method
1. If it finds the object in cache it will not hit the database?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding,

**Load** hits the cache and **Get** also tries to hit the cache.

If **Load** gets the object in cache it returns, `if not, it returns just a proxy object with the given identifier set`.

If **Get**, gets the object from cache it returns, `if not, it goes to DB and returns the found object, if not present returns null`.

Incase of **load**, if it returns the proxy object, it throws `org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException` while saving/updating the object, when the identifier of the object queried for is not present in database.

So basically use `Load` when you are sure you have the object against queried identifier in database, it's use should be where we just need to update few attributes.

Comment: and what happens if class is final